# Use sed to remove a block of duplicated text

Tags: sed, uniq

The data looks like this

```
Para1
X12Y1
AABBAABABA
BBAAABABAB
Para2
X13Y2
ABABAABAAB
ABABABABAA
Para3
X13Y2
BBBABABABA
BABABABABA
Para4
X12Y1
BBBABABABA
BABABABABA
Para5
X20Y9
BBBABABABA
BABABABABA
```

How to remove the Para3 and Para 4 base on the rule that X13Y2 and X12Y1 been duplicated ?

Desired output as below:

```
Para1
X12Y1
AABBAABABA
BBAAABABAB
Para2
X13Y2
ABABAABAAB
ABABABABAA
Para5
X20Y9
BBBABABABA
BABABABABA
```

Comment: Does every record contains 4 lines?

Answer (score 0):

**awk** solution:

```
awk '/Para/{ p=$0 }/^X[0-9]/ && !a[$0]++{ rn=NR+2; printf "%s\n%s\n",p,$0; next }NR<=rn' file
```

The output:

```
Para1
X12Y1
AABBAABABA
BBAAABABAB
Para2
X13Y2
ABABAABAAB
ABABABABAA
Para5
X20Y9
BBBABABABA
BABABABABA
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^Para/{N;H;N;N;x;s/^(.*)\n.*(\n.*)$/\2\1/;/^(\n[^\n]*)(\n.*)*(\1)/{x;d};x}' file
```

On matching a line beginning `Para`, append the index (line 2) to the hold space (HS), append the following 2 lines to the pattern space (PS), swap to the the HS and prepend the index to the front of the line (separated by a newline), check to see if that index is already present in the HS and if so swap back to the PS and delete that entry, otherwise swap back to the PS and print that entry.